# Compare the new sample in a high sampling rate datalogger

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, sd-card, timers, datalogging

I am using sdFat library the analog bin logger example,

[Github: SdFat/SdFat/examples/AnalogBinLogger/](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/tree/master/SdFat/examples/AnalogBinLogger)

The program is working fine and every thing but the thing is, this high speed datalogger uses interrupts and timers to make the ADC work at a pre-determined sampling frequency and it DOES NOT use the normal `analogRead ()`

What I want is, when the input of some analog pin is bellow a pre-determined value, I want to write HIGH or LOW to some digital pin, 
my question is, how can I compare the new sample in the analog bin logger example as I simply want to compare the new sample as in:

```
if ( analogRead() < 256 ) {// do something}
```

knowing that there is no analogRead() in the program because it uses timers and interrupts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function

```
ISR(ADC_vect) {
```

the variable `d` contains the current sample:

```
  // Read ADC data.
#if RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
  uint8_t d = ADCH;
#else  // RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
  // This will access ADCL first.
  uint16_t d = ADC;
#endif  // RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
```

So you can just "do something" depending on what is in `d`.  Of course, since this is a timer interrupt you have limited time to do anything, so you need to make sure that whatever you do is fast and efficient - so really you want to be using direct port access instead of digitalWrite().

Comment: this is perfect, thanks 

but how to know which analog pin that this d value belongs to, because more than one channel are being used? @majenko

Comment: @SabirMoglad Try looking at `adcindex`.